# Vue.js difference between method declarations

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, scope

Something I noticed today confused me.

When I first used Vue there were two common ways to define a method.

```
methods: {
    foo: () => {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and

```
methods: {
    foo() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Both worked without any problem.

Today I defined a method like the first example and I had problems with the scope of `this` inside the function.

For context:

I have data defined like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        fooVar: ''
    }
}
```

and my method was defined like this.

```
methods: {
    foo: () => {
        console.log('Foo: '+this.fooVar);
    }
}
```

When I checked the console it said

```
Foo: undefined
```

I then change the method declaration to

```
foo() {
    console.log('Foo: '+this.fooVar)
}
```

and it worked without any problem.

So since I thought that `foo() {...}` and `foo: () => {...}` are the same thing (apart from the declaration itself) I was wondering if the scope of the function changes between those two ways.

Does it change and if so why does it change?

Comment: I came across the same problem and I found [this article](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis) helpful. Kindly check [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) of es6 too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This not so much a question about Vue as about javascript itself.

In short, arrow functions(defined with (x) => { doSomething(x); } are not the same as usual functions. They have no "this" of their own and have access only to the scope they are defined in (if there is no scope, this defaults to window or global(in nodejs)). They should preferably be used in places where they don't function as methods for an object instance.

Answer (score 3):

You stumbled upon the significant difference between 'classic' function declaration and `fat arrow` declaration.

The main difference is related to how `this` is treated. 
When using `function` to declare a function you'll get a new `this` object (Note that sometimes the new `this` object is actually `undefined`). When using `fat arrow` declaration you'll end up using the `this` from the scope where the function is declared.

The main reason fat arrow was introduces is the fact that, in callbacks, when wanting to access the declaration scope `this` you had to save that value using a different name and use it. For instance

```
function doSmth () {
 var times = 0
 var that = this //or var self = this
 setInterval( function () {
  that.times ++
  console.log(that.time)
 }, 1000)
}
```

This was cumbersome and fat arrow syntax was introduced. Also the new syntax is shorter and (arguably) easier to understand.

Another important difference between `fat arrow` and `function` declaration is that [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) doesn't work on fat arrow declaration. Because `this` is bound to the declaring scope it is not changed by the call to `apply`. This is important because there are libraries counting on the fact that they can change `this` when calling a callback. They usually make this difference known in the docs, but it is important to be aware of the distinction.